# I feel like I'm "stealing" rep?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

There have been a few occasions where a user has asked a question, and an answer has been given, well recieved, and accepted. I then might have something to add, but it is usually too long for a comment, so I develop it into another answer.

I do begin the answer with something like "In conjuction with 's answer..." so that I recognize the orginal answer is valid, while my answer may provide another perspective.

However, on a few occasions, after a day or two, the OP accepts my answer. IMO, I feel like this is "stealing" the rep from the other user.

Is this wrong? And if so, what can I do to avoid this from happening?

Comment: It's the asker's perogative to accept, unaccept, or [not accept](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/questions-that-have-correct-and-upvoted-answers-that-remain-unchecked) answers, which can be entirely separate from whether or not the answer is any good. Ultimately, the site is about gathering high quality content, and if you outshone another answer enough for the OP to switch the acceptance, then that's a win for the site . Yours might not be the "best" answer, but if it's the one that helped OP the most, don't feel guilty about "stealing" the acceptance from another answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Robotnik says, it is the asker's perogative to accept, unaccept, or not accept answers. Assuming the user accepts the answer in good faith, we can assume that your answer actually helped the user more than the original answer.

That said, having your answer accepted only gives you **+15** reputation, which is only a minor increase to the **+10** reputation you earn from any user up-voting your answer.

Ultimately, you should not be worried about "stealing reputation", unless you are simply re-posting the original answer. If you are adding new information, you are posting correctly. It is important to remember that *an accepted answer is not necessarily the best answer, or even the correct answer; it is just the answer the original asker found most helpful*.

Good (and bad) answers are more accurately brought to light through voting, and given we can vote on each answer individually, posting an alternate solution (or additional information) does not really detract from the original answer. If the original answer is really as good as you think it is, other users will still vote on it, and award that user reputation. If you look back and notice your answer is significantly higher voted, it likely means that more users found your answer helpful, in which case you are more deserving of the extra reputation than the original poster.